# Sort a pandas dataframe by the second string in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in `pandas`:

```
            Player        Pos  G   IP  H  R  ER  BB  K   ERA  W  L
6       Andre Duffty      RHP  1  0.2  0  0   0   1  1  0.00  0  0
4          Chad Ring      RHP  1  1.0  0  0   0   2  0  0.00  0  0
5        Jake Johnson     LHP  1  1.0  0  0   0   0  2  0.00  0  0
```

I need to sort it by the last name. So far I have been able to sort it by the first name with:

```
batting_df = batting_df.sort_values(by=['Player'])
pitching_df = pitching_df.sort_values(by=['Player'])
```

How do I sort it by the last name, not the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort_values` and specify as `key` a function to extract the last word:

```
df.sort_values(by='Player', key=lambda x: x.str.split('\s+').str[-1])
```

Alternatively, you can reverse the order of the words to benefit from first name secondary sorting in case of identical last names:

```
df.sort_values(by='Player', key=lambda x: x.str.split('\s+').str[::-1])
```

output:

```
         Player  Pos  G   IP  H  R  ER  BB  K  ERA  W  L
6  Andre Duffty  RHP  1  0.2  0  0   0   1  1  0.0  0  0
5  Jake Johnson  LHP  1  1.0  0  0   0   0  2  0.0  0  0
4     Chad Ring  RHP  1  1.0  0  0   0   2  0  0.0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!! I googled everything I could think of and couldn't find an answer. Would you mind explaining how this works? I don't really understand what's happening with the lambda

Comment: The lambda splits the Series' values on spaces and either takes the last element (1st solution) or reverses the elements (so that `'Andre Duffty'` would give `['Duffty', 'Andre']`)

Comment: Thanks. The thing I didn't get is why the str was added. I thought it could just be x.split()[-1] but I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Those are the `str` accessors of the `Series` object (`x` in the `lambda` would be a `Series`), check the doc for [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for instance.